# Inserting a record with an apostrophe in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

This is not working and I've tried a lot of things. htaccess file specifying magic off. Code below is abbreviated for quickness.

Here's my PHP:

```
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textfield']['name']);
```

Here's my SQL command:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tblmentors (name) VALUES ('$name')
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

If there's an apostrophe in the form textfield, slashes are stored and screwing up everything.

Comment: check for ' whereever you find it , replace it with \' and then insert

Comment: If you were using MySQLi or PDO bind variables as you should be (this is 2013, not 2003); then this wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Try `strip_slashes( )` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Warning: mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.Please don't use `mysql` to develop new code.

Comment: Just noticed that Magic Quotes are on by default in the PHP Config - don't know if I can change that since the hoster has it on by default - is this possible to change...had it flagged to Off in my HTACCESS file

Comment: PHP 5.2 by the way...

Answer (score 3):

There is some "magic sanitize" function used in your application to "cleanse" user input.
Being totally useless, it is also spoiling your data as well.

You have to locate and get rid of it.

Double-check magic quotes too. On modern servers `.htaccess` just doesn't work.

And you definitely have to move toward **prepared statements** instead of manual escaping.

Comment: If [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are turned on, your server is not only configured incorrectly, it's running a super old version of PHP.

Comment: Let me google that for you: just type "remove magic quotes" in your browser's address bar and hit the very first link appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

If that fails, try this:

```
// I prefer to stripslashes() then mysql_real_escape_string().
// If you want, just skip it and do mysql_real_escape_string inside the else part.

if (function_exists ('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
   $tmp = stripslashes ($_POST['textfield']['name']);
}
else
{
   $tmp = $_POST['textfield']['name'];
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string ($tmp);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblmentors (name) VALUES ('{$name}')";
mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error ());
```